# Local Binary Patterns for 3D images. - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, pattern-recognition

Matlab's extractLBPFeatures (from R2015b) works only on 2D images but I need to extract Local Binary Pattern features from a CT image (3D).

There are other implementation available for 2D version for LBP extractions... Is it possible to modify 2D to 3D without losing sanity? ex of 2D algo: http://www.cse.oulu.fi/CMV/Downloads/LBPMatlab

If someone come across a program/algo that can work on 3D images, please share.

Answer (score 2):

It does not exist a definition of LBP in 3D, only in 2D, for the simple reason that it's not clear which path follow to go around the voxel and and create the code.

However, you can compute the LBP code for each plan XY, XZ and YZ. So each voxel will generate three codes instead of one.

Comment: There are actually methods to compute LBP in 3D data... eg: [this paper](http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/download/fe_bu_icpr08.pdf) (pdf). Haven't got around to reading it yet, so can't add anything else.

Your suggestion to generate LBP for three orthogonal planes however seems promising. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it. Basically, they take N points on a sphere, define an order in theses points, and compute the LBP code. Then, they compute all the possible rotation of the sphere (which change the points order), and keep the minimum code value, as the classical LBP